# Changing styles in a TextView: can you call getText and then setSpan?

Tags: android, textview

Can you call getText() on a TextView, and then call setSpan() on the resulting object?  I know it works (at least on the phones I've tried in 2.2 and 2.3), but the doc for getText() clearly says that you cannot modify the result of getText().

setSpan sure looked like a modification, but after carefully reading the documentation I'm not so sure:

```
setSpan(Object what, int start, int end, int flags)
Attach the specified markup object to the range start…end of the text, or move the object     to that range if it was already attached elsewhere.
```

I can read that as saying that the only change is to the markup object (in which case you're not violating the doc condition of no mods to the Spannable).

Is this a bad hack that will break like a twig in the next release?  Or is calling setSpan() somehow exempt from the "don't change this" doc for getText()?

(Another update: the FAQ explicitly says to do this: http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/commontasks.html, so I'm thinking it's just misleading doc.)

Answer (score 0):

`TextView.getText()` returns `CharSequence`, not `Spannable`, so you can't assume that the result will be `Spannable`. Even if it is `Spannable`, changing spans will not affect `TextView`'s visual representation. And certainly such assumptions shouldn't be made because Android is open source system and every manufacturer can modify it somehow. So you shouldn't rely on implementation details.

Comment: TextView will guarantee that it returns a Spannable; check out the documentation for android:bufferType.

Comment: I edited the original question to talk about whether or not setSpan actually changes the Spannable.

Comment: `TextView` guarantees that it returns a `Spannable` only if its buffer type set to `spannable` or `editable`. If you just set a `String` to a `TextView` and do not change the buffer type, then this string will be returned, but not a `Spannable`.

Comment: At first, thanks for your link. Seems that it's OK to add spans to a result of the `TextView.getText()` if it casts to `Spannable`. I looked through the sources and understood why. Spans and their positions are stored an a separate array so they doesn't affect a text buffer. `SpanStringInternal` notifies about span changes using the `SpanWatcher` interface. `TextView` implements this interface so it redraws itself when spans are changed. That means I was wrong in my answer and this way of changing styles doesn't violate any rules from the docs.